# How do I return a range view from a function?

Tags: c++, c++20

What is the right way to implement the function below to allow the caller to iterate over the range it returns?

```
#include <set>
#include <ranges>

std::set<int> set{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

auto find_range(int a)
{
    //What type should I return?
    return std::make_tuple(set.lower_bound(a - 3), set.upper_bound(a + 3));
}

int main()
{
    for (int x : find_range(5)) {...}
}
```

The function returns a couple of iterators pointing to 2 and 9, so the loop should iterate over 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to return from the function. Could you show an example value of `set` and the desired output?

Comment: @cigien updated the post

Comment: Are you looking to return a container or a view? Containers carry the data while views are based on some other source of data (which could be, e.g., a container or instructions for how to generate the sequence).

Comment: @chris I need a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a [`subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange) like this

```
auto find_range(int a)
{
    return std::ranges::subrange(set.lower_bound(a - 3), 
                                 set.upper_bound(a + 3));
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bnT6717s3).